# Not sure how and where I am stuck in this infinite loop

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory, infinite-loop

I am getting a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:` Java heap space exception in my code. I tried putting in print statements to see if I am stuck in an infinite loop. I know that my last loop is in the infinite loop as when i set the variable `"i"` to `count` how many iterations I had to stop my program when it reached `250000`. Why am i stuck in this infinite loop and how would I fix it?

Comment: Exactly where are you checking `i < 250000`

Comment: i just declared i outside the loop and put i in the last for loop, i kept on increasing well beyond 250000 but I manually stopped the program once it got to that area of number

Comment: He's printing `i` out each time he goes through everything. He says he killed the program when `i` got to 250,000. But the printout and incrementation of `i` happens inside 4 nested loops... if each loop only happens 23 times, you'd get to 250,000 real fast (23*23*23*23 = 279841). How do you **know** that that's wrong?

Comment: How many orders are there in 'it'?  Do you know?

Comment: there are around 1000 orders

Comment: I get to a point where it says java.lang.OutOfMemoryError so i am assuming im caught in an infinite loop

Comment: You are never clearing temporaryOrderSampleSet.  Is that correct?  (That doesn't sound very *temporary*.)

Comment: Good catch, @Paul. You either want to clear it or, probably better, move the declaration/instantiation of `temporaryOrderSampleSet` to just before you use it inside the second loop.

Comment: Well i wanted to add in the orderSample to teh samples but I cannot do it in the loop or I would get the concurrentModification exception, so i created the temporaryOrderSampleSet as a new varaible to add in teh orderSample

Comment: sorry, just so I understand this right, I want to move the temporaryOrderSampleSet.add(orderSample): to what location? or my second option is right under the temporaryOrderSampleSet.add(orderSample); use temporaryOrderSampleSet.clear();?

Comment: Should your second 'for' loop be after - and not in - your first 'for' loop, maybe?

Comment: so put the second for loop inside the third for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are actually getting into an infinite loop because of the line

```
temporaryOrderSampleSet.add(orderSample);
```

You keep adding orderSample objects to this set and then immediately check all the members of that same set. So you start with 1 and check that 1, then the second is added and you check 1 and 2, then the 3 is added and then you check 1, 2 and 3, etc...

Comment: Yes, if you need to. Is this the functionality you want, to check every single object in the most inner loop?

Comment: Yes I am trying to put each attribute inside the sample then the sample which now contains the attribute inside the order, so i want the first attribute to go into the first sample and that to go into the first order, then for the second attribute to go into the second sample to go into the second order etc.

Comment: where would I clear the set then? afterr the second for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You are never clearing temporaryOrderSampleSet.  This that correct?  It is going to grow pretty quickly.  (Also, it doesn't sound very *temporary*.)